# PHP: request static property from variable value

Tags: php, oop

Is there a way to access class static property using variable value, like below:

```
class test
{
    private static $test_var = 4444;
    public function get_data()
    {
        $variable_name = 'test_var';
        return self::{$variable_name}; //returns:4444,
    }
}
```

thx,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `$$`:

```
self::$$variable_name;
```